# empty the value of the input field

Tags: javascript

I am trying to replace the value of the input with nothing when someone clicks on it,

I tried the below, but i keep getting this error in the console, can you help me out

> elem.addEventListener is not a function

**HTML**

```
<input type='text' name='first-name' value='first name' class='fieldedit' />
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('fieldedit');

    function fieldedit() {
        if (this.value == this.defaultValue) {
            this.value = '';
        }
    };

    if(elem){
        elem.addEventListener('focus' , fieldedit , false ) ; 
        elem.addEventListener('blur' , fieldedit , false ) ; 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like object of elements, not just a single element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to addEvent listener to an array, you need a specific element.  For all fields:

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('fieldedit');

for (var i=0; i<elem.length; i++) {
    elem[i]. // apply your function here
    // do your processing here
}
```

Comment: it only works on one field, but not all the ones that have the same class

Comment: that is correct, you would have to loop it through and array of elements of class`fieldedit`

Comment: im sorry Jarek but how can i do that ?

Comment: for(var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++)
{ //if condition? }

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns something similar like an array of elements. You therefore need:

```
for(var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++){
    elem[i].addEventListener('focus', fieldedit, false); 
    elem[i].addEventListener('blur', fieldedit, false); 
}
```

Comment: it only works on one field, but not all the ones that have the same class

Comment: Then replace the if by (I have updated my answer):
`for(var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++){ elem[i].addEventListener('focus', fieldedit, false); elem[i].addEventListener('blur', fieldedit, false); }`

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementsByClassName returns an array 
try appending addEventListener on the first item of array
check this snippet

```js
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('fieldedit');

function fieldedit() {
  if (this.value == this.defaultValue) {
    this.value = '';
  }
};

if (elem.length > 0) {
  elem[0].addEventListener('focus', fieldedit, false);
  elem[0].addEventListener('blur', fieldedit, false);
}
```

```html
<input type='text' name='first-name' value='first name' class='fieldedit' />
```

Comment: it only works on one field, but not all the ones that have the same class